# Can old native applications run on Windows8 tablet version?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-8, windows-runtime

[image]

I don't understand this picture well.
In the Metro style Apps, what does C/C++ mean? Native C/C++? or is it managed C++? They(Metro style apps) don't even have Win32 layer!

To make an application which compatible with both Metro style and Desktop, should we only use .NET code? The old native applications can run on Windows8 Tablet?

Comment: surely native apps run like Windows Explorer itself runs, as normal Desktop application on the right side. I imagine that also native C/C++ apps can use Metro as I see on the left there is some C/C++ going upwards even without XAML.

Comment: There's a Win32 layer listed on the right, middle column at the bottom

Comment: @Mystere I'm talking about Metro style apps.

Comment: As I understand it, metro apps can't use win32

Comment: @Benjamin - You were not talking about Metro style apps because you were asking about "old native applications".  "old native applications" do not use Metro, so your comments are confusing at best.

Comment: @Mystere: agree. actually I was confusing what Metro apps are. Sorry, just forget my comment.

Comment: @David, C++ metro apps can use a subset of Win32.  Look in the SDK folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include)

Comment: I'm not really sure what question you are asking here.  Your title is different than the first question which is different than that last question.  Can you focus this a bit more?

Comment: The subset of Win32 APIs that can be used by Metro apps is now documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757(v=VS.85).aspx. This also applies to .NET apps, which can call this using P/Invoke and COM Interop, same as usual.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes old apps, including unmanaged native apps written with C/C++/Win32 and managed ones in .NET, will run on a Windows 8 tablet fine. Except of course if the tablet is running an ARM processor; then it will only support the new Metro-style apps (and also apps which specifically target the ARM).

In the picture, C/C++ means unmanaged native apps sitting on the WinRT API, which is also unmanaged native. There will be seamless integration with .NET for those that want to use C# or VB.NET.

On your last question, you can't make an application which is compatible to both Metro-style and Desktop ... they are mutually exclusive - you have to make a choice.

Comment: hek, then should we make a pair of programs? Software companies can't give up desktop app for PC, and can't give up MetroUI for tablets either :(

Comment: Metro C++ apps are not managed. Despite the outward similarity of the new syntax to C++/CLI, it's a different thing.

Comment: @Pavel thanks for the clarity - so the metro C++ is using XAML and yet is not managed .net? that's bizarre ;-)

Comment: @HG1 Yes. You could say that the big deal about WinRT is that it lets us provide a .NET-like rich, high-level class library to C++ (and JS, and hopefully others will join the fun) without them having to take a dependency on CLR and its services such as GC and JIT.

Comment: "Except of course if the tablet is running an ARM processor; then it will only support the new Metro-style apps."  - It's my understanding that even old applications which are ported by their developers to ARM will run on the ARM processor just fine.

Comment: @Brian: Yes it's little confused. I guess if we recompile old legacy apps for ARM core target, it will be run fine on ARM tablets.

Comment: @Brian, my understanding that those old win32 apps will not run on ARM  as they are now, but you will need to recompile them to be able to run them on the ARM machines.

Comment: Yes I.E. they will not have something like WOW64 support. But I think it'll be a bit more than a simple re-compile.

Comment: RE Metro: "(and also apps which specifically target the ARM)". Does this mean that Apps made for Metro part of WinRT will also have to be recompiled and or code altered if made with C# and XAML (Not JS/HTML5) in order to run on Win8 ARM based devices ?

Comment: @LaserBeak Metro apps will run fine on ARM without code changes. Not sure about recompiling though. I think they are packaged into a format similar to .NET assemblies and so they may not need to be recomiled either.

Comment: no, the only API available for ARM will be WinRT. Your old code that uses the old APIs will not run at all, no option to port either. http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2012/02/windows-8-on-arm-the-desktop-is-there-sos-office-but-not-much-more.ars

Answer (score 5):

WinRT is native code, and C/C++ are native, although their Syntax when used with WinRT looks like C++/CLI. From what I hear, it seems like an API that was designed for C++ rather than C, so it's very object oriented and people seem rather excited.

C# will use the usual way of COM Interop to use WinRT.

To quote Andy Rich (MSFT) from [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/f50be099-ba75-4a47-9f69-207c9080735e):

> Core WinRT is NOT managed - it is native and COM-based.  Our language provides a fully-native projection of that in a high-level syntax, but you aren't tied to that syntax - you will be able to target the Windows Runtime using low-level COM or WRL (an ATL-like template library) as well.  (The C#/VB projection is a different story, they generate runtime-callable wrapper objects which marshal between .NET and WinRT.)

Comment: So can you have a metro application with 0 reliance on managed code?

Comment: @Brian, yes.  If you write in either C++ or JavaScript, there will be no managed code involved.

Comment: @Brian, that probably means yes - but you will need to cross-compile and ARM has quite a few variants.

Comment: When selecting metro C++ app in VS2011 you have code that looks like managed C++. I think it is, do you know of any links that show how to make a native metro app?

Comment: :) Example: `void SampleDataItem::OnPropertyChanged(String^ propertyName);`

Comment: You want this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454076(v=VS.85).aspx. Basically it looks a lot like C++/CLI, but there are differences, and the output is pure native code. Consequently, there's no GC, and `^` types are actually refcounted smart pointers, and strings are `HSTRING`.

Comment: Also, "C# will use the usual way of COM Interop to use WinRT" is wrong. WinRT has a special projection to .NET that is different from COM Interop, and much more seamless and low-level. For example, a WinRT type is seen as a CLR type, so much so that you instantiate them using `newobj` IL instruction - CLR takes care of going to WinRT for the whole activation business. And there are no interop assemblies at all - you directly reference .winmd files.

Comment: So it sounds like they compile down to something that runs natively but they redefined the meaning of what native c++ means (real c++ based on a real published standard)?  Sounds like (managed c++)++;

Comment: What are they calling this new COM technology? COM++ ;-)

Comment: @Brian "Native" has always meant "not bytecode" / "not needing a VM to run". You're thinking about "standard C++" here. Now, because this is, ultimately, COM, you can use plain old C++ with it. There's a library called WRL, similar to ATL, that lets you do it with a bunch of smart pointers and other helper classes, and macros to implement interfaces. But it's as much of a hassle to deal with as COM ever was - you end up with 2x-3x code for the same task, most of it boilerplate, and it's non-portable anyway because you use WinRT APIs. Also note that standard C++ is still a full subset.

Comment: @Brian see "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\winrt\wrl\" in Developer Preview.

Comment: Pavel: My objection wasn't with the native part, or its meaning.  My objection was with the unmarked up usagae of the name C++.  Thanks for the winrt\wrl  path

Answer (score 4):

C++ in Metro apps is native C++. It is recommended that you use the [new language extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454076%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which look a lot like C++/CLI, and provide a similarly high-level experience - e.g. no need to manually deal with reference counting objects and strings, or implementing and calling `QueryInterface` - but in pure native code. You don't have to do that, though.

In any case, for your own classes, you can define them in vanilla C++, and compile them to a library. This way, you can share your logic between the desktop version of your app (with UI implemented using MFC, Win32, Qt or whatever) and the Metro version (with UI implemented using WinRT APIs). Similarly, for .NET apps, you can separate logic into a class library that's reused between desktop and Metro.

There's no way to write a single app that will run on both with the same UI layer, neither in C++ nor in .NET. On the other hand, you can approximate that to some extent with HTML/JS, if you avoid using WinRT APIs and stick to HTML5 standard - then you can make a "desktop version" by hosting it in a browser.

Comment: Okay, thaks for the clear answer. And I decided. I won't learn the new and weird C++. I always will use C# when I make Metro apps.

Comment: @Benjamin My personal preference is also for C#/VB, because of the three available choices it's the only one that has `async` and `await` - and with so many operations in WinRT (like in Silverlight) being async only, it comes in very handy. And I don't suffer from GC-phobia :) But to each their own - that's why there are all these choices.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a professional software developer, and while I write mainly enterprise web-based applications, I have played around with Visual Studio 2012 and Windows 8. Here's what I've discovered:

Since Metro is now a verboten term, I'll use the term "Tablet apps" to refer to full-screen apps and "Desktop apps" to refer to programs running on the Windows desktop.

> I don't understand this picture well. In the Metro style Apps, what does C/C++ mean? Native C/C++? or is it managed C++? They(Metro style apps) don't even have Win32 layer!

All tablet apps use managed code. This is because the WinRT operating system can't run x86 or AM64 instructions. Both versions can run .Net code just fine, though. So all WinRT apps must use managed code, use a XAML UI, and they will only be distributed through the Windows Store.

> To make an application which compatible with both Metro style and Desktop, should we only use .NET code?

Yes. That's exactly right. You must use .Net code. Old, native apps can NOT run on a Windows 8 tablet. If you're like most Windows devs who learned by doing, this is going to require an adjustment in how you write code.

Here's how I am approaching it:

A basic program that needs to operate on different form factors (tablet, desktop, phone) will have 3 classes. The Model and the Controller classes will be implemented in a DLL, along with an Interface file that defines the GUI events and methods. The only thing that actually goes in to my .EXE files is the GUI. And the only logic in the GUI is basically to raise an event when the user performs actions on the form that require the program to do something.

For example, the user fills out his name on a text field, then clicks "Submit." That would raise an Submitted event with the value from the Name box as a parameter. The controller can send feedback back to the form with a method, such as UpdateStatus()

It sounds complicated, and it takes more up-front design. The beauty of this system is that once you implement the program for one form factor, all you have to do is modify your XAML for the other form factors. Your controller and your model don't change at all. (I'm sure that someone will point out how to use XAML templates to do this, but I'm not there yet.)

Answer (score 1):

As with Windows 7, 64 bit Windows doesn't support old 16 bit apps.  Other than that, yes, native apps are supported.